# c++ stl functions template type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I've been looking around in, and coding some basic examples for std::algorithm and for some reason i never found it odd that they work like this for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
  std::vector<int> vec;
  vec.resize( 100 );

  std::generate( std::begin( vec ), std::end( vec ), std::rand );   
  auto element = std::max_element( std::begin( vec ), std::end( vec ) );
}
```

How come it does not require template parameters like this:

```
std::generate<std::vector<int>::iterator>( ... 
std::max_element<std::vector<int>::iterator>( ...
```

Comment: your title already has the answer... `std::being(vec)` is a `std::vector<int>::iterator`, so no need to tell it to the compiler again

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking why you don't need to explicitly define an iterator for generate() and max_element? std::begin and std::end return iterators and the type of the vector is included in vec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [std::generate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) possible implementation:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *first++ = g();
    }
}
```

Here `ForwardIt` type is deduced by the compiler from `first` and `last` parameters.

Then, both [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) functions return iterators for the container. These are *std::vector* iterators in your case.

Consequently, `ForwardIt` is deduced as a type of *std::vector* iterator and you do not have to specify it explicitly.

The same logic applies to other algorithms.

Comment: Edited the post to correct a small issue and i just want to add that _template argument deduction_ is the key word if op want to search more on this subject.

Comment: @Zlatomir thanks for providing the answer with a better wording)

Answer (score 2):

`std::begin` and `std::end` return iterators so you don't need to tell it explicitly to the compiler. Also as you are passing the vector as a parameter to those two functions, the compiler will know the template parameter.